# Why do I get "Sequence contains no elements"?

Tags: c#, linq

**NOTE: see edits at bottom. I am an idiot.**

I *had* the following code to process set of tag names and identify/process new ones:

```
IEnumberable<string> tagNames = GetTagNames();
List<Tag> allTags = GetAllTags();

var newTagNames = tagNames.Where(n => !allTags.Any(t => t.Name == n));

foreach (var tagName in newTagNames)
{
    // ...
}
```

...and this worked fine, except that it failed to deal with cases where there's a tag called "Foo" and the list contains "foo". In other words, it wasn't doing a case-insensitive comparison.

I changed the test to use a case-insensitive comparison, as follows:

```
var newTagNames = tagNames.Where(n => !allTags.Any(t => t.Name.Equals(n, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

... and suddenly I get an exception thrown when the foreach runs (and calls MoveNext on) newTagNames. The exception says:

> Sequence has no elements

I'm confused by this. Why would `foreach` insist on the sequence being non-empty? I'd expect to see that error if I was calling `First()`, but not when using `foreach`?

---

**EDIT**: more info.

This is getting weirder by the minute. Because my code is in an async method, and I'm superstitious, I decided that there was too much "distance" between the point at which the exception is raised, and the point at which it's caught and reported. So, I put a try/catch around the offending code, in the hope of verifying that the exception being thrown really was what I thought it was.

So now I can step through in the debugger to the foreach line, I can verify that the sequence is empty, and I can step right up to the bit where the debugger highlights the word "in". One more step, and I'm in my exception handler.

**But**, not the exception handler I just added, no! It lands in my outermost exception handler, without visiting my recently-added one! It doesn't match `catch (Exception ex)` and nor does it match a plain `catch`. (I did also put in a `finally`, and verified that it does visit that on the way out).

I've always taken it on faith that an Exception handler such as those would catch *any* exception. I'm scared now. I need an adult.

---

**EDIT 2**:

OK, so um, false alarm...  The exception was not being caught by my local try/catch simply because it was not being raised by the code I thought. As I said above, I watched the execution in the debugger jump from the "in" of the `foreach` straight to the outer exception handler, hence my (wrong) assumption that that was where the error lay. However, with the empty enumeration, that was simply the last statement executed within the function, and for some reason the debugger did not show me the step out of the function or the execution of the next statement at the point of call - which was in fact the one causing the error.

Apologies to all those who responded, and if you would like to create an answer saying that I am an idoit, I will gladly accept it. That is, if I ever show my face on SO again...

Comment: Could you provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Are you sure this error is not coming from `GetTagNames()`? Try adding a `.ToList()` after it for testing purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing that error. But I think you want `String.Compare()`. `Equals` compares references types by seeing if they refer to the same object, which is not what you want here.

Comment: What's the CLR type of exception? - by looking at exception concrete type, you can guess which operation is throwing it. Otherwise you are looking into cloud of options...

Comment: @JonathanWood No it doesn't.  It overloads the `Equals` method to compare the underlying values of the string.  It does a reference comparison first as an optimization, to possibly short circuit (all `Equals` can optionally do this), but that's not really relevant.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Even if this *weren't* using an overload, `String.Equals(object)` *overrides* `Equals` to provide a contents comparison, not a reference comparison.

Comment: @Tengiz: the type of the exception caught is InvalidOperationException, BUT I'm not sure whether this is the original exception or not - see my edit.

Comment: @Jon: will do, but it'll take a while (I'm leaving the office now).

Comment: Then look into inner exception.

Comment: @Tengiz: There is no inner exception.

Comment: If you've got an exception which can't be caught, that's very, very odd... and I'll need to see it with my own eyes before I believe that it's really happening and not just a quirk of your diagnostics, I'm afraid. If you *can* reproduce it, that would be fabulously interesting though.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is a red herring you're chasing. Did you do what @Magnus suggested? This will at least help eliminate the chance that the error is totally unrelated to your rather innocuous LINQ change.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as proper or clean, but how does this work:

```
var newTagNames = tagNames.Where(n => !allTags.Any(t => t.Name.ToUpper() == n.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: I downvoted because you're providing a suggestion to compare strings differently, which does not at all address the question.

Comment: @DavidB To be fair, he did say the problems started happening when he changed to string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling is fun on deferred actions.  The Enumerable.Where method (and most linq methods) are not executed until the query is enumerated.

```
IEnumerable<int> query = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
int myNum = 0;
try
{
  query = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(i => (i/myNum) > 1);
}
catch
{
  Console.WriteLine("I caught divide by zero"); //does not run
}

foreach(int i in query) //divide by zero exception thrown
{
  //..
}
```

---

In your particular case:

```
IEnumberable<string> tagNames = GetTagNames();
```

I bet `GetTagNames` has a Enumerable.First or Enumerable.Single inside there somewhere.  If the result of GetTagNames is deferred, you must enumerate that result to get the exception to occur.  That is why the commenters are recommending you call ToList on the result of GetTagNames - to enumerate it and get the exception to occur before your use of tagNames in a complicated query.